# Having 2 or more components subscribe to a cold Observable provided by an Injectable

Tags: angular, rxjs, subscribe

sorry if this is trivial.

I'm new to Angular 4 and I'm struggling with a seemingly simple issue:  having 2 or more components subscribe to an `Observable` provided by a (login) `Injectable`.

My goal is to have:

1. A view invoke an event on `component1`
2. `component1` will invoke a method on a `login.service`
3. `login.service` will make a REST call
4. The response is "broadcast" using a `.next()`
5. `component1` and `component2` will react accordingly

This works perfectly when there is only 1 component but when I introduce another component that `subscribe()`s to the `Observable`, the 2nd component only gets notified at the very beginning (ie: it only receives one message) whereas `component1` continues to work as expected and receives all messages.

I initially used `Subject` and `BehaviorSubject` with the `asObservable()` method but then fell-back to plain `Observable` with similar results.

Here is a snippet to help demonstrate:

`login.service:`

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

    private _loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<booelan>(false);
    public loggedIn$ = this._loggedIn.asObservable();


    login() {
        // call API service
        this._loggedIn.next(true);
    }
 }
```

`component1:`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-test1',
    template: `<button (click)="login()"`,
    providers: [ LoginService ]
})

export class AppTest1Component {
    subscription: Subscription;
    observer: Observer;

    constructor(private loginService: LoginService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = this.loginService.loggedIn$.subscribe(
            state => { console.log('got event!', state); },
            error => { console.log('Error:', error)},
            () => { console.log('Complete'); }
        );
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
   }
}
```

`component2:`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-test2',
    template: `<button (click)="login()"`,
    providers: [ LoginService ]
})

export class AppTest2Component {
    subscription: Subscription;
    observer: Observer;

    constructor(private loginService: LoginService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = this.loginService.loggedIn$.subscribe(
            state => { console.log('got event!', state); },
            error => { console.log('Error:', error)},
            () => { console.log('Complete'); }
        );
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
   }
}
```

What is the simplest way to have several components subscribe to an `Observable` that would presumably be provided by a service, and receive ALL messages?

The question posted here: [Angular - shared service between components doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43997489/angular-shared-service-between-components-doesnt-work) does not related to Observables and Subscriptions.

Comment: That question may not be related to the observables but it addresses the same problem. Please read the answer and try it in your app.

Comment: You are bang on.  Sorry for not taking the time to thoroughly read the response.  I had tunnel vision.

Comment: Happens to the best of us :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by echonax, your issue seems to be related to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43997489/angular-shared-service-between-components-doesnt-work?noredirect=1&lq=1) .

By adding LoginService as a provider of both components, you are actually creating 2 instances of the said service.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-test2',
    template: `<button (click)="login()"`,
    providers: [ LoginService ] /* you are creating a new instance of the service here /*
})
```

If you want to have the same instance, or what is called a shared service, you have to declare the provider in the module they are in and remove the providers in the components :

```
@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [LoginService],
    ...
})
```

If by any chance the two components you mentionned are in seperate modules, you have to declare the service as providers in one module, and then import this module to the other :

```
/* NgModule of the Module2 */
@NgModule({
    imports: [
    Module1], /* you import the module which has the service as provider */
    providers: [] /* Really important point here, you have to leave providers blank or at least with no reference to the shared service, or you will create a new instance of the said service */
   ...
})
```

I'm not totally sure it would solve your problem, but I'm almost certain you have to use a shared service anyway in your app, based on the code you provided.

Comment: You are both correct.  Thank you Echonax and nvkfr.  I struggled with this all day.  I had already declared the service in my @NgModules but I foolishly instantiated a new copy in each component as you saw in my snippets.  Once I removed the Providers from both components, everything worked perfectly.  THANK YOU!