# Calling methods between components in angular using service not working

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui, injectable

I am trying to call a method in one component from other component using injectable service

My first component (I'm calling method in other component from this component)

**bottombar.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectorRef, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Label } from "ui/label";
import { BottomBarService } from '../../services/bottombarservice/bottombar.service';

@Component({
  selector: "bottom-bar",
  templateUrl: "./components/bottombar/bottombar.html",
  styleUrls:["./components/bottombar/bottombar-common.css", "./components/bottombar/bottombar.css"],
  //providers: [BottomBarService]
})

export class bottombarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private bottomBarService: BottomBarService) {

  }

  openDrawer(){
    this.bottomBarService.callSideDrawerMethod();
  }
  ngOnInit() {}


}
```

From the above component I'm trying to call a method in **SideDrawerGettingStartedComponent** which is present below which will trigger a method that opens side drawer

My Second component (In which the called method is present)

**sidedrawer.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from "@angular/core";
import { Page } from "ui/page";
import { ActionItem } from "ui/action-bar";
import { Observable } from "data/observable";
import { RadSideDrawerComponent, SideDrawerType } from "nativescript-telerik-ui-pro/sidedrawer/angular";
import { RadSideDrawer } from 'nativescript-telerik-ui-pro/sidedrawer';
import { BottomBarService } from '../../services/bottombarservice/bottombar.service';

@Component({
    // moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "tk-sidedrawer-getting-started",
    templateUrl: "./components/sidedrawer/sidedrawer.html",
    styleUrls: ['./components/sidedrawer/sidedrawer.css'],
    //providers: [BottomBarService]
})
export class SideDrawerGettingStartedComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
    private _mainContentText: string;

    constructor(private _changeDetectionRef: ChangeDetectorRef,private bottomBarService: BottomBarService) {
      this.bottomBarService.sideDrawerMethodCalled$.subscribe(() => {
        console.log("subscribed")
        alert("hello")
        this.openDrawer()
      })
    }

    @ViewChild(RadSideDrawerComponent) public drawerComponent: RadSideDrawerComponent;
    private drawer: RadSideDrawer;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.drawer = this.drawerComponent.sideDrawer;
        this._changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.mainContentText = "SideDrawer for NativeScript can be easily setup in the HTML definition of your page by defining tkDrawerContent and tkMainContent. The component has a default transition and position and also exposes notifications related to changes in its state. Swipe from left to open side drawer.";
    }

    get mainContentText() {
        return this._mainContentText;
    }

    set mainContentText(value: string) {
        this._mainContentText = value;
    }

    public openDrawer() {
        console.log("triggered openDrawer in main component")
        this.drawer.showDrawer();
    }

    public onCloseDrawerTap() {
       this.drawer.closeDrawer();
    }
}
```

And Shared service is as below

**bottombar.service.ts**

```
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class BottomBarService{
    private sideDrawerMethodSource = new Subject<any>();
    sideDrawerMethodCalled$ = this.sideDrawerMethodSource.asObservable();

    callSideDrawerMethod(){
        console.log("Inside service bottomBar")
        this.sideDrawerMethodSource.next(null);
        console.log("after")
    }
}
```

**Problem**

I have an html associated with **bottombar.component.ts** which contains a button. On tap it will trigger openDrawer() function in **bottombar.component.ts**

I can see the consoled value in my service file, but somehow it is not triggering the subscribe in **sidedrawer.component.ts**

There is no error and because of that it is difficult to find what is exactly causing the issue.

Also I have declared my service in **ngModule**'s provider to avoid singleton issue.

Is there something that I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular - shared service between components doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43997489/angular-shared-service-between-components-doesnt-work)

Comment: I tried that solution which is declaring service in `ngModule` as I mentioned in last lines, It is not working even after providing the service at the root

Comment: Read the answer carefully, you still re-provided your service inside your `@Component` annotation

Comment: Are you sure that your `sidedrawer` component is loaded?

Comment: @echonax I have overlooked the answer, I changed the code according to the your solution by providing only in `ngModule` . Still I don't get the console values in **sidedrawer.component.ts** component. 

I have upated the answer too .

Comment: @AmitChigadani Yes, because I didn't getting any errors while importing it.

Comment: @Yeshwanth why are you not using `EventEmitter` ?

Comment: My question is whether `sidedrawer` constructor is executed at least once or not? Try to log before doing subscribe and check.

Comment: @Abrar `EventEmitter` is suitable only when two components have `parent-child` relationship.

Comment: @Yeshwanth, ya my mistake. I wrote a solution below

Comment: @AmitChigadani u r right, I tried to console a value before subscribing, even that is not coming up. What could be the reason?

Comment: Seems that `<tk-sidedrawer-getting-started> </tk-sidedrawer-getting-started>` component is never triggered from the html template or it is blocked by some condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your shared service, instead of passing `null` here `this.sideDrawerMethodSource.next(null)`, you can pass a `status:boolean`. In your **bottombar.service.ts**  -

```
callSideDrawerMethod(status:boolean){
    this.sideDrawerMethodSource.next(status);
}
```

Now, in the **bottombar.component.ts**, pass a status when invoking the method -

```
this.bottomBarService.callSideDrawerMethod(true);
```

In your **sidedrawer.component.ts**, pass a `status` param -

```
  this.bottomBarService.sideDrawerMethodCalled$.subscribe((status) => {
        console.log("subscribed")
        alert("hello")
        this.openDrawer()
      })
```

And instead of subscribing in the constructor, place the code in `ngOnInit()` life cycle hook.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked along with @AmitChigadani's comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you missed to append `'$'` next to `sideDrawerMethodCalled`

Try below code:

```
callSideDrawerMethod(){
        console.log("Inside service bottomBar")
        this.sideDrawerMethodSource$.next(null);
        console.log("after")
    }
```

Comment: my variable in line private `sideDrawerMethodSource = new Subject<any>();` doesn't have the `$`. So I didn't use it that way. Anyways I tried appending `$`, still its not working