# In Angular 4 or Angular 2 Typescript how To call in component of methods or variables in another component

Tags: angular, typescript1.5

suppose i want to call A component {} of variables or methods in B component in Angular 4 or Angular 2

Comment: Possible duplicate [Angular shared services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43997489/angular-shared-service-between-components-doesnt-work)

Comment: Here is the component reference about types of interaction between angular components [Components Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)