# Service variable when passing data from one component to another angular 2

Tags: angular, variables, typescript, scope

I am trying to pass a variable from one component to another. I am doing that by using a service:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';


    @Injectable()
    export class SharedService {
      // private questionNumber = new Subject<number>();
      // questionNumber$ = this.questionNumber.asObservable();
      questionNumber : number;
      publishData(number:number) {
        this.questionNumber = number;
        console.log(this.questionNumber,'publish');
      }

  getQuestionData(){
    console.log(this.questionNumber,'get');
    return this.questionNumber;
  }

  constructor() { }

}
```

If the data gets changed in the function "publishData" it writes the current variable value in the console:

[image: publish Variable]

But if I try to access that variable it is still undefined as if it isn't changed

[image: Undefined get]

Component 1 (excerpt) :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from '../shared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-quiz',
  templateUrl: './main-quiz.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-quiz.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  providers: [SharedService]
})
export class MainQuizComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _sharedService: SharedService){
    this._sharedService = _sharedService;
  }

  updateQuestion(){
    this._sharedService.publishData(this.questionNumber);
  };
```

Component 2:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from '../shared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-win-page',
  templateUrl: './win-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./win-page.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  inputs: ['questionNumber'],
  providers: [SharedService]
})
export class WinPageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _sharedService : SharedService) {
    this._sharedService = _sharedService;
    this.questionNumber = this._sharedService.getQuestionData();
   }

  questionNumber : number;

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  ngOnChanges(){
    this.questionNumber = this._sharedService.getQuestionData();
  }

}
```

Why isn't that variable updated ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: how do you call it? maybe you're getting the variable before it's set?

Comment: In my second component:  ngOnChanges(){
    this.questionNumber = this._sharedService.getQuestionData();
  }

Comment: Can you share the component codes? (with their `@Component` annotation)

Comment: Yes, I added the component that needs the data.

Comment: where do you set it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular - shared service between components doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43997489/angular-shared-service-between-components-doesnt-work)

Comment: How did you get the output `1 "publish"`? From where you are setting the value? I mean from where you are calling the `updateQuestion` method of the service? Better add a plunker

Comment: The output 1 publish do I get after hitting a button in my first component. There the publishData() function gets called and outputs the "1 publish

Comment: Thanks, echonax didn't find that question...

Comment: Would it be better to delete the question because it has already been answered ?

Comment: @Snixells it would've been better if you've marked it as duplicate :-) but no problem if you have found your answer.

Comment: @echonax how do i mark it as duplicate ?

Comment: @Snixells https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79916/is-it-possible-to-mark-my-own-question-as-duplicate-of-another

Comment: @echonax I cant find a close button...

Comment: @Snixells how about https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147341/discussion-between-snixells-and-echonax).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already answered here: [Angular - shared service between components doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43997489/angular-shared-service-between-components-doesnt-work)

Each component has :

```
providers: [SharedService]
```

So based on the angular [DI Hierachy](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection) the service will be available only for the current component.
In your case that mean each components will have his own instance ([service isolation](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#scenario-service-isolation)).

If you want your component to share the same instance you need to declare the provider at the module level.