# Passing a user defined number between component through service angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

example.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ExampleService {

    number1 : number;
    number2 : number;
    result : number;
    constructor() { }

}
```

component1.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ExampleService } from '../example.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'app-component1',
    templateUrl: './component1.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./component1.component.css'],
    providers: [ExampleService]
})
export class Component1Component implements OnInit {

    number1v = null;
    number2v = null;
    resultv = null;

    constructor(public aService : ExampleService ) { 
        this.aService.number1 = this.number1v;
        this.aService.number2 = this.number2v;
        this.aService.result = this.resultv;
    }
    ngOnInit() {
    }
    processForm(){
    this.resultv = this.number1v + this.number2v;
    }
}
```

component2.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ExampleService } from '../example.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'app-component2',
    templateUrl: './component2.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./component2.component.css'],
    providers: [ExampleService]
})
export class Component2Component implements OnInit {
    resultv;
    constructor(public aService : ExampleService) { 
        this.aService.result = this.resultv;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
    getResult(){
        alert(this.resultv)
    }
}
```

Want to pass a value of result from component1 to component2.

> No parent to child or child to parent component.

the result i get is undefined.

Comment: Use this [**blog post**](https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular - shared service between components doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43997489/angular-shared-service-between-components-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

The problem, is when component A updates the service, component B is not aware of the changes. So, to solve this we need to use Observer pattern and let all observers be informed of the change.

Luckily Angular comes with rxjs, so we can use `BehaviorSubject` to implement the observer pattern.

Service Code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ExampleService {

    number1 = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
    number2 = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
    result = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
    constructor() { }

}
```

Inside component you can read their values

```
service.number1.subscribe(num => {
   // ....
});
```

To change any number you can just update it this way

```
service.number1.next(1); // set new number
```

Ofcourse this is crude way, you can get better examples reading online tutorials or answers on BehaaviorSubject